# Why can's a thread make a blocking system call (user level threads)?

Tags: operating-system

I am reading Modern Operating System (4th edition). I am not really sure about this paragraph.

> Despite their better performance, user-level threads packages have some major
>   problems. First among these is the problem of how blocking system calls are implemented.
>   Suppose that a thread reads from the keyboard before any keys have
>   been hit. Letting the thread actually make the system call is unacceptable, since
>   this will stop all the threads.

If a thread blocks waiting for an input, can't another thread be off doing something else? Why it would "stop all the threads"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue that statement addresses is that user threads are implemented as a library. There is a main thread that manages other threads. The main thread uses timers to switch among the various threads. On most [all?] Unix implementations a blocking I/O call blocks the timers from being delivered to the main thread and all threads come to a halt.

In kernel threads, the operating system (not the process) schedules threads for execution so this is not an issue because the kernel is not blocked.

Keep in mind that the quoted statement is not true for user threads on all operating systems. Many non-unix systems will deliver timer notification to a process even when there is a blocking I/O request pending.

Comment: From the Tanenbaum OS book it is mentioned the following: "in user level threads, if a thread starts running, no other thread in that process will ever run unless the first thread voluntarily gives up the CPU". This contradicts with your statement "The main thread uses timers to switch among the various threads." Could you explain it?

Comment: That is only true with SOME operating systems (notably eunuchs). Systems with software interrupts have no problem.

Answer (score 5):

User level threads are implemented in user code; they are not scheduled individually by the kernel. All user level threads run in the context of a single kernel-scheduled task and therefore one can not preempt another. So when a user thread makes a system call, it blocks,  and there is no way for another user thread (in the same kernel-scheduled task) to execute.

Note that this is *not* how most threads work on modern OSes. pthreads on Linux and threads created by CreateThread on NT kernels are scheduled individually by the kernel.